# undefined method `title' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation: // post.previous.title

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to create links for a previous post, and the next post. The reason I am not using `will_paginate` is because instead of having the text "Previous", I would like to have it as the title of the post ( i.e post.title).

To do this, I followed another answer, and created the following relation in my Post Model:

```
  def previous
    Post.where(["id < ?", id].last)
  end

  def next
    Post.where(["id < ?", id].first)
  end
```

This is what I have in my `_posts` partial. Right now I'm keeping the HTML , because it has quirky styling, and I'm not sure how to include the image and span in a rails `link_to` tag.

```
             <% if post.previous %>
            <a href="#" class="action-left">
              <img src="img/arrow_red_right.png">
              <span><%= post.previous.title %></span>
            </a>
            <% end %>
```

I get the error :

```
undefined method `title' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007f8145616250>
```

I am guessing it has something to do with the way I defined previous in the Post Model. Help appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to fix the parenthesis in your methods :)

```
def previous
  Post.where("id < ?", id).last
end

def next
  Post.where("id > ?", id).first
end
```

Comment: In the `next` method, I believe the query should have a greater than sign (>): `Post.where("id > ?", id).first`

Comment: ah yep you're right. you should comment that on the question itself so the OP would know :)